# Why are there different types of arrays in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query `select array_agg(id) as idtag FROM POdelivery_a where ....`

It gives me  `id` in array: `{26053,26021,26055}` I use it later in other queries...

for the question assume I use it like this:

```
select * from a where id in {26053,26021,26055}
```

it gives me an error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"

it will accept the query as:

```
select * from a where d in (26053,26021,26055)
```

So why `array_agg(id)` returns me an array that I can not work with? I always need to do conversions...

is there a way that `array_agg(id)` will return the result as `(26053,26021,26055)` not as `{26053,26021,26055}`?

Why does PostgreSQL works with many kinds of arrays?

Comment: `(26053,26021,26055)` is **not** an array. And `{26053,26021,26055}`  is just the **text** representation of an array (explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO)

Comment: Is there a function that can return data in form of `(26053,26021,26055)`? What i'm doing now is take the `{26053,26021,26055}` and replace the Brackets... its not very stylish...

Comment: Don't aggregate the result into an array: `where id in (select id from ...)`

Comment: The query I showed `select array_agg(id) as idtag FROM POdelivery_a where ....` isn't my real query... it's was used to explain my situation. The real query is over 20 lines. I care about the result: `{26053,26021,26055}` and the result will be used in many other places... i won't run the query every time.. I need to save the results....

Comment: Then show us the complete query. To re-use the result of a sub-query you can use a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: Will it calculate the query just once or every time its called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a overlap of PostgreSQL arrays and SQL lists (sets). These types are very similar in modern SQL, but in typical usage there is semantic gap. A array is one no atomic value, that can be calculated and stored. A list (set) is usually multirow result of some subselect (can be stored in modern SQL too).

Examples:

```
-- the array constructors
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]
SELECT array_agg(someval) FROM tab

-- the list constructor
VALUES(1),(2),(3)
SELECT id FROM tab

-- filtering
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3])
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id = ANY (SELECT array_agg(...))
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id IN (SELECT idf FROM ...)
```